# How to access multiple variables of looped selector in one form?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a matching game with ruby on rails. I currently have a for loop that displays an actors picture, and then besides each of those pictures, I have a selector that gives you an option of each of the possible actors names. I want the submit button to call a javascript function (check_answers) that would check for the id's of the actor (who's picture is shown) compared to the names. For each of the correct matches you'd get a point and the form action would move you to a new page that would display your score (how many you got right).

It makes sense to me to have one submit button (because the person should just fill out all of their answers and then submit) but I'm not sure then how to access the variable for each of those answers in just one call to check_answers().

```
 <% actor_array = @actors.find_random_actors %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var points = 0
  function check_answers(){
    for (i = 0; i < actor_array_json.length; i++) {
      <!-- here I would want to compare whether the actor id is equal to the submitted id. Below it would have been iter.id == person.id -->
      if (){
        points = points + 1;
      }
    }
}
  </script>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <form method="post" action="/scores">        
      <!-- for each actor in the array, display their picture -->
      <% actor_array.each do |iter| %>
      <tr>
        <td><img src =<%= iter.file %> width = '200px', height = '200px'></td>
        <td>
          <select id="answer">
          <% actor_array.each do |person| %>
            <option value=<%=person.id %>><%= person.name %></option>
             <% end %>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
   <% end %>
   <tr><td> <!-- new row for the submit button -->
   <input type="button" onclick="check_answers()" value="Submit">
    </td></tr>
```

[image: For you visual people, here'a picture.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should name your `select tag` like this

```
<select id="answer_<%= iter.id %>">
```

Then in your script, we can check (I use Jquery, you can change to Javascript if required):

```
for (i = 0; i < actor_array_json.length; i++) {
    if ($('#answer_' + actor_array_json[i].id).val() == actor_array_json[i].id){
        points = points + 1;
    }
}
```

But if we do this, user can show your HTML to know the answers.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly how I ended up doing it.